# How to prevent credential pop up?

Tags: credentials

It's only happening for one user where he keeps getting authentication pop up. After 4/5 attempts he can go to the document library page. Then when he clicks on a word file (where version and checkout is enabled) he gets endless pop up for credential.

No else having this trouble. I took following actions but problem still exists.

IE: Tools – Internet Options - Advanced tab – confirm Enable Integrated Windows Authentication is selected.

Not sure if i need to go through the steps in this link because about 2000 people are not seeing this but 1 employee. http://paulliebrand.com/2008/04/02/sharepoint-consistently-prompting-for-user-credentials/

Comment: Scenario 1 and 2 from that link are valid checks. Confirm those and let us know.

Comment: I remember this happens because the user is not correctly made in User Profile or UserInfomationList.. Solution was to delete the user from SharePoint, user profile, UserInformationList and then sync the user again with User Profile Service! This question was previously asked by someone, I just can't find it!

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri: That particular users in so many sites so I can't just delete him from all the sites and re add them. Can you think of any other solution?

Comment: @DavidLozzi: I will try the link and go through some of the items. Some of the internet explorer settings are admin driven and are pushed through GPO. I can't even see all the trusted sites in the intranet zone as the list is grayed out and it's longer (meaning scroll down is disabled too).

Comment: try opening IE with no add ons, should be an option in the All Programs list. Also, I'm assuming this is IE8/9?

Comment: Also make sure that his IE proxy is configured correctly if using one.

Comment: Okay, I had the troubled user log off and I logged in to his pc. I can click on the document, I see the yellow check out bar in MS Word, I can check out, edit, save, check back in. So if the IE setup is wrong it would behave the same way when I logged into user's machine. I already took 2 hours from the user and he doesnt seem happy about it. LOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Chizzel, I installed fiddler and found 401 error for "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll". after googling I found this article "http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/choroshin/archive/2012/11/06/sharepoint-getting-authentication-login-prompt-when-trying-to-open-office-document-with-unique-permissions.aspx" which talked about disabling "lockdown" feature. walla, everything started working like I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the Office Diagnostic Tools first, if this doesn't work then run fiddlr2 on the client box to see what requests are being made when the document is opened. You should be able to see whats requests and response are being made. This might give you a clue...

[image]

Comment: I dont have that type of luxury when I am with the user. He is already irate. I had him log off and i logged in to his pc and my profile works as expected. Something tells me is not sharepoint or IE or local. It's his profile. I am clueless as to what else.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you, fiddler saved me so many times.